# Can't get gunicorn service to start with socket

Tags: django, unix, service, gunicorn, systemd

I have a Django and Gunicorn setup. If I start the Gunicorn service from the command line like this:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 first.wsgi
```

from the following working directory:

```
~/code/firstdjangoproject/first
```

everything works as expected.

However when I try to setup a service with `systemd` for gunicorn with the following `gunicorn.service` configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/firstdjangoproject
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --error-logfile - /home/pi/error.log \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          first.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get the following error when trying to access the site with `curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn.sock localhost`:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

When I look at the logs `sudo systemctl status gunicorn` I get the following:

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-09-30 22:14:14 CEST; 7s ago
  Process: 3070 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --error-logfile - /home/pi/error.log --workers 3 --bind uni
 Main PID: 3070 (code=exited, status=210/CHROOT)

sep 30 22:14:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
sep 30 22:14:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=210/CHROOT
sep 30 22:14:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
sep 30 22:14:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
sep 30 22:14:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
sep 30 22:14:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
sep 30 22:14:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: How you pass the setting for your django project? I think there should be something like EnvironmentFile or Environment which allow you to set the environment variable for gunicorn service. And btw, could you please restart gunicorn and update the logs? Most of my cases I have to restart gunicorn then the error will come after that..

Comment: How should I restart gunicorn? I don't get any new information if restart the service with `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`

Comment: I mostly use this: `sudo service gunicorn restart`

Comment: 1. See if there's anything useful in `/home/pi/error.log`. 2. Try running your `ExecStart` command manually. Copy/paste exactly what you have in the command, switch to the `WorkingDirectory`, make sure you're running the command as `pi`, and see if there is any more useful error output.

Comment: @GregKaleka thank you for your suggestion. There was indeed an error in the working directory path.  The working directory line should have been `WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/code/firstdjangoproject/first`. Thank you very much for your help.